# Android SQLite does not found in Inntellij's DataSoruce

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, intellij-idea

I am developing flutter using Intellij.
And I am currently using the sqflite plugin in PJ.

I read the following article.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/accessing-android-sqllite-databases-from-product.html

I tried to access the sqlite database in android from Intellij.
However, "Android SQLite" is not displayed in DataSource.
I would like to know how to display android sqlite in datasource.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that Android plugin is enabled via [plugins management](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) settings. If it's enabled try to perform the following steps:

- Close the IDE.
- Remove `.idea` and `.gradle` folders.
- Create Android project from existing sources. **(File | New | Project from Existing Sources...)**